# How can i put <hr /> between the List? PHP

Tags: php, html, pdo

Code:

```
                    <?php
                    $row_questions = DB::$handler->prepare("SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc, postDate FROM questions ORDER BY postID DESC LIMIT 4");
                    $row_questions->execute();
                    while ($row = $row_questions->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        echo "<section id=\"question_title\">{$row['postTitle']}</section>";
                        echo "<section id=\"question_body\">{$row['postDesc']}</section>";
                        echo "<a href=\"question.php?id={$row['postID']}\">Frage weiterlesen..</a>";
                    }
                   ?>
```

How can i put under each Question a hr, without on the latest question?

Comment: Since your query has a `LIMIT 4`, you could use a simple counter var, i.e. `$count = 1;` that you increment on each loop, and if it is less than 4 echo the `<hr />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before while:

```
$i = 1;
$number_of_rows = $row_questions->fetchColumn();
```

into while:

```
if($i < $number_of_rows) echo '<hr>';
$i++;
```